# How to datetime format accurate asia/jakarta

Tags: codeigniter, datetime

I have input data for date and time but after being stored in the database the time is not in accordance with the time of day I was in Asia/Indonesia. What's the solution?

```
public function permohonan()
{

    $id_permohonan     = $this->input->post("id_permohonan", true);
    $id_member         = $this->session->userdata('id_member');
    $data_diminta      = $this->input->post("data_diminta", true);
    $tujuan_penggunaan = $this->input->post("tujuan_penggunaan", true);
    $status_permohonan = 1;
    $tanggal           = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $keterangan        = "";

    $data = array(
        'id_permohonan'     => $id_permohonan,
        'id_member'         => $id_member,
        'data_diminta'      => $data_diminta,
        'tujuan_penggunaan' => $tujuan_penggunaan,
        'status_permohonan' => $status_permohonan,
        'tanggal'           => $tanggal,
        'keterangan'        => $keterangan,
    );

    $this->Tb_permohonan_model->insert($data);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Create Record Success');
    redirect(site_url('frontend'));
}
```

And the data stored in the database is:  `2018-08-13 05:14:21`
this is not accurate with my time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may help you.

In the application/config/autoload.php put this below line.

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Indonesia");

It will set the default time zone.

Answer (score 0):

You can set default timezone in config file e.g: date_default_timezone_set(Asia/Jakarta).